# Android - install app from Android Studio - missing shortcut in android device

Tags: android, android-studio

Maybe its a dump question, but I am using Android Studio to run the application I'm building in android devices. After I installed it, there is no shortcut for my app created in the android device's programs.

How can I fix this? Is it an Android Studio option?

Comment: Make sure that you have <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>                                                                                           in yout MainActivity tag of the manifest file...

Comment: yeap..that was missing..it was dump indeed.. thanks!

Comment: Please accpt the answr...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have

`<intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
</intent-filter>`

in yout MainActivity tag of the manifest file...